# Conforming class to protocol using RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm

I've defined a `protocol ExampleProtocol` with a property `exampleArray` of type `[Stuff]`. This protocol is defined within a framework so that I can use it in my AppClip version as well.

`Stuff` is another protocol.

Here's my protocol:

```
public protocol ExampleProtocol {  
    var exampleArray: [Stuff] { get set }
}
```

I'm using `RealmSwift` for local storage, and I've created a class `Example` that conforms to `ExampleProtocol`. However, I'm encountering an error stating, "Type 'Example' does not conform to protocol 'ExampleProtocol'." How can I resolve this issue?

class with Realm:

```
class Example: Object, Identifiable, ExampleProtocol {
    @Persisted var id = UUID().uuidString
    var exampleArray = List<Stuff>()
}
```

where the class in AppClip is defined differently:

```
class ExampleAppClip: Identifiable, ExampleProtocol {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var exampleArray = [Stuff]()
}
```

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to fix this error and ensure that my class correctly conforms to the protocol.

Comment: Great answer by @TayyabMubeen. It's not clear why the code is written in the way it is. You've defined a protocol requiring conforming classes to have an Array `[Stuff]` but then the class doesn't conform to the protocol because it uses a RealmSwift.List `<Stuff>()` which are two very different things. Additionally, this `var exampleArray = List<Stuff>()` is not how to use a persisted Realm List, it should be `@Persisted var exampleList = RealmSwift.List<Stuff>()`. Maybe if you can update the question as to *why* that's being done and what you're attempting to do, we may be more help.

Answer (score 1):

In your protocol you defined simple array of type stuff but array and List of Realm are two different types. You need to change it in your protocol and in your app clip class.

```
public protocol ExampleProtocol {  
    var exampleArray: List<Stuff> { get set }
}
```

and conform it like

```
class ExampleAppClip: Identifiable, ExampleProtocol {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var exampleArray = List<Stuff>()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to avoid incorporating Realm into both my framework and AppClip. Secondly, it's worth noting that Stuff is a protocol that does not conform to 'RealmCollectionValue'.

Comment: then i think a singleton class would be better and one benefit of this that it will have only one list in memory!

Comment: @MjDev The comment *I'd like to avoid incorporating Realm* is a little confusing as the code incorporates a `RealmSwift.List` as a property, which is Realm. If you want to avoid using Realm in any capacity, that should be an Array instead, of course you then loose the option to persist the data. Can you clarify (the question) what what the intention is?

Comment: @Jay I have three targets in my project: the main app, the AppClip, and a framework. In the main app, I've implemented RealmSwift for data storage. However, for the AppClip and the framework, I aim to avoid using Realm entirely.

Comment: @MjDev If you're not using Realm in the other objects, then the Protocol should just be for those other objects. e.g. The protocol is for uniformity and conformity and the Example Realm object doesn't match that, and in fact has different functionality entirely (it's persisted, which the other objects are not) so it should not conform to that protocol at all.